# The search icon won't appear when using MDBIcon

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mdbreact

I want to display the search icon along with the search bar in my Navbar in React Bootstrap

**src/modules/home/Home.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InformationTableView from '../../components/InformationTableView'
import { CustomButton } from '../../components/CustomButton'
import {Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Form, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel ,InputGroup} from "react-bootstrap";
import ReactBootstrap, {Jumbotron, Col, Grid, Panel,NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { MDBCol, MDBIcon } from "mdbreact";
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css'

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <Navbar className="bg-light justify-content-between">
                    <Form inline>
                        <MDBCol md="6">
                            <form className="form-inline mt-4 mb-4">
                                <MDBIcon fab icon="search" />
                                <input className="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Account Number" aria-label="Search" />
                            </form>
                        </MDBCol>
                        <InputGroup>
                    </Form>
                </Navbar>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Is there an error in this code segment?

Comment: Check if you have included the bootstrap CSS link in your `public/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Hi You missed Fontawesome stylesheet in the root file
add this link to your Html root file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```